# Display Street Address in multiple lines

Tags: magento-1.9

1) Below is **Street 1** address entered by customer & displaying in **invoice** pdf :

[image]

I am getting **Street 1** address in **Custom pdf**. but its displaying in single line.

2) My **custom** Pdf :

[image]

**Issue** :

its not displaying complete Street 1 address.

**Requirement** :

Restrict Number of charactars & words in single line so that complete street  address will display in multiple lines.

```
$page->drawText($shippingAddress->getStreet(1) , 20, $page->getHeight()-240);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the string using `str_split` then loop through the resulting array, drawing it line-by-line.  For example:

```
$addressArr = str_split($shippingAddress->getStreet(1), 20);

foreach($addressArr as $line) {
    $page->drawText($line, 20, $page->getHeight()-240);
}
```

The `20` at the end of the first line would split it into chunks of 20 characters (see [PHP Manual on str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)), and the loop may require you to move down the page for each line, depending on whether you are using extensions and which ones.  If you haven't already seen it, [Boost My Shop](https://www.boostmyshop.com/global-pdf.html) has a free extension for PDFs of all kinds, with documentation.  It is free, and **it has a built-in function for Multiline Text**.

Answer (score 1):

i used [textChunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) & [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

```
$line = 600; 
$textChunk = wordwrap($shippingAddress->getStreet(1), 50, "\n");
foreach(explode("\n", $textChunk) as $textLine)
{
  if ($textLine!=='') 
  {
    $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($textLine)), 20,  $line,  'UTF-8');
    $line -=20; // increase space between words
  }
}
```